# Is HANDLE similar to file descriptor in Linux?

Tags: c++, windows, file-descriptor

Is HANDLE similar to file descriptor in Linux? As far as I know, HANDLE is used for handling every resources on Windows, such as font, icons, files, devices..., which in essence is just a void pointer point to a memory block holding data of a specific resource

Comment: Yes, same thing.  It isn't a pointer btw.

Comment: A Windows HANDLE is a sort of token for a kernel object (always referring to objects that have been loaded into memory). The OS creates a mapping to the kernel objects and the handle (passed to user space) is the "key" to that mapping. Notice there can be different handles for the same kernel object (even in the same process) and the OS will not destroy the object until you close all the handles.

Comment: Print out the HANDLE values... you'll see they're not pointers. Thing is, it doesn't matter what the values represent, you shouldn't care. So yes, they're both provide the same functionality but use different methods.

Comment: But you should make a difference between _true_ kernel HANDLEs, which are, plainly speaking, those closed with `CloseHandle()`, and other objects that are syntactically similar but are not kernel objects, such as window handles (HWND), GDI objects (HICON, HGC, HBITMAP), HMENU, etc.

Comment: Are you asking if they are conceptually similar or if they are implemented similar?

Comment: @rve since you mention, i think it would benefit everyone if we know both.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, Windows handles are very similar to Unix file descriptors (FDs).

Note that a `HANDLE` is not a pointer to a block of memory.  Although `HANDLE` is `typedef`'d as `void *`, that's just to make it more opaque.  In practice, a `HANDLE` is an index that is looked up in a table, just as an FD number is.

This blog post explores some of the similarities and differences:
http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2015/05/passing-fds-handles-between-processes.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are conceptually similar. File descriptors in unix map integers to a per-process table of pointers to other objects (which can be other things than files, too). File descriptors are not as unified though -- some things exist in a separate "namespace" (e.g., process timers). In that respect, Windows is more orthogonal -- CloseHandle will always free a resource regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that handles refer to a far broader concept on Windows. Even we restrict the discussion to only file handles, there is significant differences. There is a function called _open_osfhandle() as part of C run-time library on Windows. Its purpose is to, quote "Associates a C run-time file descriptor with an existing operating-system file handle."  That is, a glue function between the kernel land and the C Run-time land.  The function signature is as below:

```
int _open_osfhandle (
    intptr_t osfhandle,
    int flags
);
```

File handles Windows is actually more feature rich than file descriptors in C, which can be configured when a file handle is created with CreateFileA (ANSI version) or CreateFile (UTF16 version), reflecting the design difference between *Nix and Windows. And the resulted handle carries all these information around with all its implications.

Answer (score -2):

A `HANDLE` is a void pointer

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef void *PVOID;
```

[Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383751)

Comment: Be careful about drawing conclusions from this.  An incomplete pointer type is a good type to use for an opaque handle because it prohibits arithmetic -- you can't accidentally add two handles together the way you can with unix file descriptors stored in `int` variables.  But a `HANDLE` is not a memory address.  And `typedef PVOID HANDLE;` is not even correct.  (Lookup the `STRICT` macro and its effect)

Comment: (Check yic81's comment "The statement `typedef HANDLE HINSTANCE;` is totally incorrect, as many other typedef HANDLEs. Vast majority of them are now `DECLARE_HANDLE()` structs." on the page you linked to.  He's right, the MSDN page is wrong.)