# Suggestion to improve my code of hangman game in python 3

Tags: python, refactoring

I'm working at this code for a hangman game built with python 3.

The code is working perfectly, as soon as you have your `words.txt` file with some words in same folder as the script, but I need suggestions to improve it.

There is a lot of code repetition and points that I could code much better, and I'm struggling in code refactoring. Any comments and suggestions?

```
class Hangman(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.secret_word = self.get_secret_word()
        self.correct_letters = []
        self.missed_letters = []
        self.error = 0

    def get_secret_word(self):
        from random import choice

        with open("words.txt") as f:
            wordsList = f.read().splitlines()
            secretWord = choice(wordsList).lower()
        return secretWord

    def read_player_input(self):
        self.inputChar = input("\nType a letter: ")

    def guess_letter(self):
        if (
            self.inputChar in self.secret_word
            and self.inputChar not in self.correct_letters
        ):
            self.correct_letters.append(self.inputChar)
            return True
        elif (
            self.inputChar not in self.secret_word
            and self.inputChar not in self.missed_letters
        ):
            self.missed_letters.append(self.inputChar)
            self.error += 1
            print(f"\nError {self.error}.")
            return False
        else:
            print("\nYou've already tried this letter.")
            return False

    def print_encoded_word(self):
        self.encoded_word = ""
        for letter in self.secret_word:
            if letter not in self.correct_letters:
                self.encoded_word += "_"
            else:
                self.encoded_word += letter
        print()
        print(self.encoded_word)

        print("\nCorrect letters: ", end="")
        for letter in self.correct_letters:
            print(letter + " ", end="")

        print("\nWrong letters: ", end="")
        for letter in self.missed_letters:
            print(letter + " ", end="")

    def game_continue(self):
        return set(self.correct_letters) != set(self.secret_word) and (self.error <= 3)

    def won_game(self):
        if set(self.correct_letters) == set(self.secret_word):
            print(self.secret_word)
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print(f"You lose. Secret word is {self.secret_word}")


def main():

    hangman = Hangman()

    hangman.print_encoded_word()
    hangman.read_player_input()
    hangman.guess_letter()

    while hangman.game_continue():
        hangman.print_encoded_word()
        hangman.read_player_input()
        hangman.guess_letter()

    hangman.won_game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (explanation below):

```py
class Hangman(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.secret_word = self.get_secret_word()
        self.correct_letters = []
        self.missed_letters = []
        self.error = 0
        self.inputChar = None


    def get_secret_word(self):
        from random import choice

        with open("words.txt") as f:
            wordsList = f.read().splitlines()
            secretWord = choice(wordsList).lower()
        return secretWord

    def read_player_input(self):
        letter = input("\nType a letter: ").lower()
        if letter == self.secret_word:
            self.correct_letters += list(self.secret_word)
            self.inputChar = None
        elif len(letter) >1:
          print("You can add only 1 letter!")
          self.inputChar = None
        elif len(letter) == 0:
          print("Please input soemthing!")
          self.inputChar = None
        else:
          self.inputChar = letter

    def guess_letter(self):
        if self.inputChar is None:
          print("Try again")
        elif (
          self.inputChar in self.correct_letters + self.missed_letters
        ):
            print("\nYou've already tried this letter.")
            return False

        elif self.inputChar in self.secret_word:
            self.correct_letters.append(self.inputChar)
            return True
        else:
            self.missed_letters.append(self.inputChar)
            self.error += 1
            print(f"\nError {self.error}.")
            return False

    def print_encoded_word(self):
        self.encoded_word = ""
        for letter in self.secret_word:
            if letter not in self.correct_letters:
                self.encoded_word += "_"
            else:
                self.encoded_word += letter
        print(f"\n{self.encoded_word}")

        print(f"\nCorrect letters: {' '.join(self.correct_letters)}", end="")

        print(f"\nWrong letters: {' '.join(self.missed_letters)}", end="")


    def game(self):
        print(self.correct_letters)
        if set(self.correct_letters) == set(self.secret_word):
            print(self.secret_word)
            print("You win!")
            return False
        elif self.error <= 3:
          return True
        else:
            print(f"You lose. Secret word is {self.secret_word}")
            return False


def main():

    hangman = Hangman()


    while hangman.game():
        hangman.print_encoded_word()
        hangman.read_player_input()
        hangman.guess_letter()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Firstly, you have to check if the user actually added a letter inside read_player_input, or if he guessed the word.

Then, you have the same logic in game_continue, and won_game, so just merge them in game.

The same logical checks where done multiple times in guess_letter, changed the tree a bit.

Also, instead of for loops for prints, you could use string formatting with join function, for less code and better performance.

Finally, hangman.game() returns True on start, so 3 lines in main were redundant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using main() as though you would expand your code and wanted to call in more functions when the program was run. Also, I would close the file after you're done with it (you can see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535973/is-it-necessary-to-close-files-after-reading-only-in-any-programming-language)).

I put a comment "#" on the functions that I would alter below:

```
class Hangman(object):
    def get_secret_word(self):
        from random import choice

        with open("words.txt") as f:
            wordsList = f.read().splitlines()
            secretWord = choice(wordsList).lower()
            f.close()       #close the file
        return secretWord


    def print_encoded_word(self):
        self.encoded_word = ""
        for letter in self.secret_word:
            if letter not in self.correct_letters:
                self.encoded_word += "_"
            else:
                self.encoded_word += letter
        print()         #what is this print doing here?
        print(self.encoded_word)

        print("\nCorrect letters: ", end="")
        for letter in self.correct_letters:
            print(letter + " ", end="")

        print("\nWrong letters: ", end="")
        for letter in self.missed_letters:
            print(letter + " ", end="")

    def play():         #add this function
            hangman.print_encoded_word()
            hangman.read_player_input()
            hangman.guess_letter()

            while hangman.game_continue():
                hangman.print_encoded_word()
                hangman.read_player_input()
                hangman.guess_letter()

            hangman.won_game()

def main():     #remove stuff that is now in play()

    hangman = Hangman()
    hangman.play()  #add this
```

I would need to know what each function does exactly to give more suggestions, but it seems that the rest is fine.